# $x_1=0,\,x_{2n}=\frac{x_{2n-1}}{2},\,x_{2n+1}=x_{2n}+\frac{1}{2}$ Find $\lim \sup {x_n}$ and $\lim \inf {x_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Define a real sequence recursively by the following equations: $$x_1=0$$ $$x_{2n}=\frac{x_{2n-1}}{2}$$  $$x_{2n+1}=x_{2n}+\frac{1}{2}$$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Find $\lim \sup {x_n}$ and $\lim \inf {x_n}$.

The definition that I am using is $\lim \sup{x_n}=\lim (\sup_{m \geq n} x_m)$ and $\lim \inf{x_n}=\lim(\inf_{m \geq n}x_m)$. I manage to find the $\sup_{m \geq n} x_m$, which is $+ \infty$  (I get this after I substitute $n$ into the sequence and find the terms). But I don't know how to find the form of $\inf_{m \geq n} x_m$. I get $(0,0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{8},\frac{3}{8},...)$. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: If you understand what $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are, you don't have to compute the inner $\sup$ and $\inf$ separately just to see the pattern. This sequence is not convergent, but it has an "upper envelope" and a "lower envelope". $\limsup$ is the limit of the upper envelope, and $\liminf$ is the limit of the lower envelope. My first guess would be that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n = 1$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = 1/2$. Once I've made a guess, then I'll have to use the definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ to verify my guess.

Comment: How did you get $\sup_{m\ge n} x_m = \infty$? Is that true for all $n$?

Comment: I don't think you've evaluated the sequence correctly? By my calculations, the first terms are $(0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{8},\frac{7}{8},\dots)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Since
$$x_{2n}= \frac14 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{n}}, \qquad x_{2n+1}= \frac12 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{n}}$$ we have
$$\inf_{m \ge n} x_m = \frac14 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{[n/2]}}, \qquad \sup_{m \ge n} x_m = \frac12 + \frac{1}{4}+\ldots=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Idea: write as a sum of fractions with denominators as powers of 2. I don't think the limsup is infinity.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can find a closed horm as follows.

Denote $y_n=x_{2n-1}$. Then from
$$
x_{2n+1}=x_{2n}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{x_{2n-2}+1}{2}
$$
you get
$$
y_{n+1}=\frac{y_n+1}{2}
$$
and find $y_n$.

Similarly $z_n=x_{2n}$ and 
$$
z_{n}=\frac{z_{n-1}+2}{4}
$$
etc.

Comment: I don't see how this helps-it's basically the same thing as the original question